# Installing Play framework on Mavericks, java 1.8.0_05

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to Scala/Java/Play Framework.

I followed the instructions at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Installing to install Java 8 (along with Netbeans) and play framework for OSX.

I created a new Scala Application using "play new myappname" and all the template files have been created.

When I try to run the application using the command "play" from inside the project directory I see the following error:

```
error: error while loading AnnotatedElement, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 76)
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? i
[warn] Ignoring load failure: no project loaded.
[error] Not a valid command: play (similar: last, alias, loadp)
[error] play
[error]     ^
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you upgrade to Scala 2.10.4 and try again? https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by uninstalling JDK 8 and installing **JDK 6 from the Apple Developer site** at http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

(Side note: First I tried JDK 7 which failed with a similar yet different error).

Comment: I can confirm this still is the case. A year later.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a chance to look at this:

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1095